# Terraform UI for non technical CLI users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud, devops, continuous-deployment

I currently have a server build process that uses Terraform and deploys a server all from code.

I'm looking for a web UI with forms that I could either populate specific fields and or do API get commands against a VCenter or wherever the server is being built to populate the specific fields. The fields that get populated would be stored as the variables.tf file and when someone hits submit, it would run the actual Terraform command terraform apply to build the server based on the variables. My guess is the terraform binaries would have to live on there so it could run in the background.

It doesn't have to be some super fancy web page, just something that I could potentially make look cool for Director level folks.

Also, I don't want to use TF enterprise, yet. I've looked into a couple of open source projects (atlantis and terrahub) but none seem to be what I'm looking for.

I'm far from a web developer so any help would be awesome.

Comment: If not TF Enterprise or Cloud, then you probably are creating a pipeline and using its UI with parameters. If you need it to "look cool", that is basically why the Blue Ocean plugin was created for JP.

Comment: @gafotas, did u find anything exciting? i am also looking for something similar...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with SLD
[Stack-Lifecycle-Deployment](https://github.com/D10S0VSkY-OSS/Stack-Lifecycle-Deployment)

I think it has everything that you need
It is very intuitive, it has a web interface and a rest api to easily integrate it with the rest of the applications.

Comment: Are you associated with the SLD project? If so you should add a disclaimer to your answers because right now you have two answers (both in the same hour) that point to this low traffic project so it looks potentially spammy.